# Ruby on Rails - Adding sort order to album images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, nested-forms

I am creating a *users album* application. User can upload many images into their album and I am using `nested_forms` for uploading images to album.

In my view when user is seeing the images that belongs to the album I want to show **X of (total_number_of_images)**.

For ex: if a album has **12** images and user is seeing the **3rd image** in that album, it would be **3 of 12** and when they click on *next* it would change to **4 of 12**, etc.

*Please see attachment*
[image]

How can I get this to work? Do I need to add a `column` in `images`-db *(how to add the sort order)* or there is other ways to do so?

This is what I have done until now:
I have added a `sort_order` column in `images`-db and does this:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :previous_slide

@slide = user.images.order("id DESC")
  @slide.find_each do |slide|
   slide.increment!(:sort_order, + 1)
  end

end
```

This actually adds increment to `sort_order column` but in wrong order since the `order` is always `id ASC` no matter what I have added myself.
I get:

```
id    sort
1      4
2      3
3      2
4      1
```

**Its has to be:**

```
id    sort
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
```

As you can see its on wrong order.

Comment: What have you done so far? How does your controller and your view look like?

Comment: yes the sord order depends on user settings, then  yes, it should be added as a column of settings in db.

Comment: Please see my new edit. I added codes that I have done until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code help to solve your problem

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
       @slide = User.images.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end


  private

  def sort_column
    User.images.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
end
```

Inapplication_helper.rb

```
 def sortable(column, title = nil)
      title ||= column.titleize
      css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
      direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
    end
```

Comment: Thanks , Do I need to add any `column` into my db?